# Change the broswer's address name

Tags: asp-classic

how can I change the broswer's address name?? For example I have this: www.example.es/Pages/site.aspx and I want this: www.example.es/site

How can I do that?? Ty.

Comment: We use a tool called mod_rewrite, it is a clone (for asp) of the apache htacces mod rewrite stuff.  Bit of a learning curve though.  Have a look at http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: You either need to do URL rewriting or use ASP.NET MVC. Are you using asp classic like the tag says? That would produce a .asp file, not .aspx.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 404 error challenge and Server.transfer() to do URL rewriting using classic asp

Things you need

- [How to create a custom 404 page](http://forums.iis.net/t/1023695.aspx)
- Regular expression pattern to recreate actual file path or a predefined list

> eg:-www.example.com/pg1/ ---> /pages/pg1.asp

- Simple server.transfer() to handle valid / invalid server requests.

> ```
> <%
>
>
> IF Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "pg1" THEN
>       Server.transfer("/pages/pg1.asp")
> ELSE
>       Response.write("404 - Page not found");
> END IF
>
> %>
> ```

- that's all you are doing basic level URL rewriting using classic asp.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about `.aspx` ([asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)) pages, but your question is tagged [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic)... you will get better responses to future questions by using the correct tag.

In this case: as long as you can install a module on your server, and you're server can process ASP.Net's `web.config` files, you can use the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) that Graham mentioned in the comments. I've got an old ASP-Classic site that uses the module just fine.

If you can install an extension, you could also use [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/). Some hosts have this installed already.

All things being equal, if you have the ability to run your choice, I'd go with the IIS URL Rewrite Module as I've generally seen better performance from it. But that may just be me.

If you do not have that kind of access to the server, and there's not something already installd, you may have to go with the 404 mapping [Jeevaka Nuwan Fernando mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641282/25163).

There are some other options, but they depend on if you are using ASP.Net or ASP-Classic.